# what is the postgres replacement lower() and like %

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

i have a working SQL statement which query the json data stored in database column "data"

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM dispenseorders.dispenseorder 
where lower(data) LIKE '%"state":"new"%'
```

but the same statement hits error at postgres database.

what should be the replacement for above?

Comment: try casting to text: `lower(data::text)`

Comment: You should probably be using the JSON functions here.  Also, your `LIKE` expression is missing a closing single quote.

Comment: updated the missing quote , will try the lower(data::text)

Comment: What is the error you get? Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete message

Comment: Are you sure you need the `lower`?

Comment: lower is used because the data value sometimes NEW sometimes new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try casting to text (`lower(data::text)`), but the better solution is to use the `->>` operator (if `state` is not a nested key):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
  FROM dispenseorders.dispenseorder
 WHERE lower(data ->> 'state') = 'new';
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)